# Efficiently generating tuples with Outer

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, combinatorics

I'm trying to efficiently generate tuples of lists of objects that satisfy a given criterion. The similar questions that I have found on this website end up finding a specific workaround for the given problem.

An inefficient way of doing what I want is

```
Select[Tuples[lists] , criterion]
```

which is inefficient because MMA first needs to generate and store all the tuples.
I'm thinking of using `Outer`, but I'm not sure how. I've tried something that in my head should work but in reality it does not:

```
Outer[If[#1 === a || #2 === 2, {##}] &, {a, b, c}, Range[2]]

(* {{{a, 1}, {a, 2}}, {Null, {b, 2}}, {Null, {c, 2}}} *)
```

What it wants to do is to leave the tuple in place if it satisfies the criterion or else remove it: I would like the output to be (in this case)

```
(* {{{a, 1}, {a, 2}}, {{b, 2}}, {{c, 2}}} *)
```

How do I do it?

EDIT:
Thanks to the comments I have put to together this solution (which gives the same output of `Select[Tuples[{list1,list2,...}], criterion@@##]`):

```
f = Flatten[Outer[If[criterion@Flatten[{##}], Flatten[{##}], Nothing]&, ##, 1], 1] &

Fold[f, {list1, list2,list3,...}]
```

Which also allows one to apply the criterion on all the elements of a tuple.

Comment: It may be much more efficient to do this recursively, and perhaps use a compiled function to do the actual selection of allowed tuples. But I cannot say for sure unless you share the actual list and condition you are interested in.

Comment: Recursively as in `Fold[Outer[criterion,##]& , list1, {list2,..}]` or do you mean something else? Each of my lists is a list of associations, and my criterion is that all the lists of associations in each tuple must be "overlapping" on at least two associations with respect to the value of a given key. (example: considering the key "b", {<|"a"->1,"b"->2|>, <|"a"->1,"b"->3|>} overlaps with {<|"a"->1,"b"->2|>, <|"a"->1,"b"->4|>} only for one value (the value 2) and a tuple containing these two lists would be discarded.)

Comment: Your approach with `Outer` will work if you specify `Nothing` as the third argument of `If`

Comment: Amazing, I did not know about `Nothing`! (And I love this paradoxical admission)

Comment: @Ziofil [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) is a _very_ new function. So, i'm not surprised you knew nothing about it.

Comment: In the past, it was called the "vanishing function" (by Mr. Wizard) and was implemented like this: `## &[]`. I still use this because I still have V10.0.

Comment: @march `##&[]` evaluates to `Sequence[]` which is broader in scope than `Nothing`. But, the biggest difference, AFAIK, is that they have different reactions to `Hold`. `Sequence` requires the `SequenceHold` attribute to hold it, `Nothing` is fine with `HoldAll` and its kin, e.g. `If[a, first, Nothing]` vs. `If[a, first, Sequence[]]`. Hence, the use of the function.

Comment: @rcollyer. I didn't realize they were actually different! I've use the `##&[]` in some silly situations involving more complicated versions of something like  `Which[expr1, ## &[], expr2, else]` vs `Which[expr1, Sequence[], expr2, else]`, where clearly the first works and the second doesn't. Anyway, someday I'll have V10.(>1), and I can use `Nothing`.

Comment: @Ziofil, I meant something else. In your case, `Outer` still tries all combinations of elements in the two lists, which may or may not be wasteful, given the lists and/or the comparison function. But unless the associations in the lists have a sort of predeterminable structure, you probably need to compare all of them, so your solution will be fine =)

Comment: @march just note that `Nothing` _only_ works in `List` and `Association`, so in a lot of cases where `##&[]` is needed, `Nothing` won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

Here is a way of efficiently generating tuples of objects that satisfy a given criterion (`criterion`, which takes a list of objects and returns `True` or `False`). We consider the general case of creating tuples from several lists of objects.

This works best if the criterion can be applied before reaching the desired tuple length. (e.g. if I want to make tuples that contain only even numbers, I can discard a partial tuple as soon as it contains an odd number).

Start by defining a filtering function that deletes lists of objects that fail to satisfy the criterion.

```
filter = Module[{tuple = Flatten[{##}]}, If[criterion@tuple, tuple, Nothing]] &;
```

Then apply it to pairs of lists using `Outer` with the third argument set to 1 (so that `Outer` stops at the first level):

```
generator = Flatten[Outer[filter, ##, 1], 1] &;
```

Finally, fold the `generator` function on all the lists of objects, one by one:

```
Fold[generator,{list1,list2,...}]
```

This makes sure that we don't carry over to the next call of `Outer` lists that already fail to satisfy the criterion.

**Performance**

We will generate random matrices (e.g. 8 by 4) of numbers between 0 and 10 and we create tuples of even numbers out of the rows.

```
testList := RandomInteger[10, {8, 4}]
criterion = VectorQ[#, EvenQ] &;
```

Then we have

```
Mean@ParallelTable[First@AbsoluteTiming[tuples@testList;], {1000}];
(* 0.027 *)
```

On my modest machine I get an average of 0.03 seconds per tuple. Let's try a different way:

```
Mean@ParallelTable[First@AbsoluteTiming[Select[Tuples@testList, criterion];], {1000}];
(* 0.28 *)
```

Done inefficiently it takes about 10 times longer, but these numbers vary wildly for different problems.

Comment: I think this is neater way `Fold[Select[(Flatten /@ Tuples[{##}]), criterion] &, lists]`. A little faster than your version